# Keep android alarms alive, even after process killed by a task manager

Tags: android, task, alarmmanager

I am writing an alarm program.
My problem is task managers, like advanced task manager or Samsung task manager, **remove my alarms** when clearing memory.
Is there any way of **preventing** task managers from removing my alarms?
Or a way to be **notified** of  "clear memory" and forcing app to recreate alarms again.

Comment: remove alarm or kill yous process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. You can re-register your alarms when the user starts your app again, or when the phone is rebooted.

Comment: Yes, but user is expecting alarms while the app is not restarted.

Comment: Tell your users to not use task killers if they need your app. If you kill an app, it's gone, that's the way it works.

Comment: You know it's hard thing to say to users, because android phone needs periodical task killing!

Comment: No it doesn't. The Android OS does a better job of handling resources than any user or self-proclaimed task manager. If it is out of resources, it will kill a process that is not used to free up memory, etc. No need to mess it up with third-party 'tools'. Read http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html and http://geekfor.me/faq/you-shouldnt-be-using-a-task-killer-with-android/ to clear your confusion.

Comment: Thank you, seems we should wait for version after 2.2 where killing processes doesnt kill alarms

Comment: You said **re-register** my alarms, actually I can remove and re-register my alarms during app startup, but is there anyway to findout **if my alarms are still active**?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `AlarmManager` doesn't provide an API for that. If you register with the same parameters (PendingIntent and request code), any existing alarms will be overwritten, so you don't really need to check.