# How to restart alarms from AlarmManager when Task Manager kills application

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, taskmanager, huawei-mobile-services

I am making an Android application where I schedule alarms in AlarmManager that trigger notifications to the user and need to go off at rigid specific times.

When a user uses a task killing program (usually from a chinese phone and ROM), the alarms are killed as well.

This is troublesome, because after this happens, no more notifications are launched untill I re-open the app or restart the phone. This is not trivial to the target user that is a layman.

These alarms are supposed to work offline, so using GCM to re-up the alarms through a network listener is not an option. I actually need some "unkillable" service on the phone that checks if the alarms still exist and reschedule them if they don't. Is this possible?

I found this post here, but the last answer was in 2012: [Keep android alarms alive, even after process killed by a task manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551287/keep-android-alarms-alive-even-after-process-killed-by-a-task-manager)

Is there currently a solution to this?

Comment: use JobScheduler instead

Comment: Instead of AlarmManager or to restart the Alarms? JobScheduler is not exact

Comment: try jobScheduler with deadline instead of AlarmManager.